# kcore file on /proc/ 128tb

Tags: virtualization, vmware, vmware-workstation, proc, vmware-tools

[my vm with windows with shared folders and my ubuntu showing the file on KDE Dolphin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcxX4.png)

**/proc/kcore - 128TB**

[a link to the file](https://file:///proc/kcore)

ok, i creating a project in a Windows VM, the Linux+Windows, copying my host files to vm using VMware Tools Shared Folders but i doesn't have 128tb on the virtual disk (vmdk), it a 70gb vmdk, and shows You need 128TB More to do this operation, i searched this in internet and very very results. what is this file??

it's a **important file?** or a **virus?** or a **normal file**, like a text document created by user (not malicious, but isn't important)

Answer (score 0):

I have never known that file to be anything other than 140737471586304, 128T. It is not important, not a virus, and it is normal. Examples:

My test 20.04 Ubuntu server:

```
doug@s19:~/vm$ ls -l -h /proc/kcore
-r-------- 1 root root 128T Apr 25 11:16 /proc/kcore
```

A Debian 11 server (different distro):

```
doug@s15:~$ ls -l /proc/kcore
-r-------- 1 root root 140737471586304 Feb  5 13:52 /proc/kcore
doug@s15:~$ doug@s15:~$ ls -l -h /proc/kcore
-r-------- 1 root root 128T Feb  5 13:52 /proc/kcore
```

By the way the size comes from 2**47, and because it is a mapping function to 47 bits of potential virtual memory.

EDIT: No, you can not delete the file. It is not really a "file". `/proc` is a way for information flow:

```
$ mount | grep proc
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
```

An excerpt from [documentation](https://tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/proc.html):

> /proc is very special in that it is also a virtual filesystem. It's sometimes referred to as a process information pseudo-file system. It doesn't contain 'real' files but runtime system information (e.g. system memory, devices mounted, hardware configuration, etc). For this reason it can be regarded as a control and information centre for the kernel. In fact, quite a lot of system utilities are simply calls to files in this directory.